# Why Database is in compatibility range and upgrade is recommended

Tags: database

This is more than a question than an issue, my question is why SharePoint Database get to this status.

Database is in compatibility range and upgrade is recommended

Regards

Comment: Did you run the Config Wizard?

Comment: yes and all is good now, my question what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After installing SharePoint patches (for SharePoint 2016+, there are typically 2 per month you need to install, for lower versions of SharePoint, you can deploy the single Cumulative Update to cover all patches), you must run the Configuration Wizard on each farm member to complete the installation process. While there have been the rare bug in the past, this resolves the Compatibility Range notifications for databases.

[Install a software update for SharePoint Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/install-a-software-update)